# Rewrite everything in root to folder

Tags: .htaccess

Im sorry, I know this question has been asked a million times but I can't get it to work. I get infinite loops or it simply doesn't redirect.

I want the following to redirect:

```
https://www.example.com
https://www.example.com/a/
https://www.example.com/b/
https://www.example.com/c/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/shop/
https://www.example.com/shop/a/
https://www.example.com/shop/b/
https://www.example.com/shop/c/
```

So far I have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ /shop/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I tried a million options, who can help?

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1
```

Comment: Somebody? I really need this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one liner Redirect for this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/((?!shop/?).*)$ /shop/$1
```

This will redirect all requests to **/shop/** including your homepage.

Note : This does not rewrite the input url , this just redirects the new url to old one changing the typed url in browser address bar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunatelly its looping now: 'https://www.example.com/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/shop/index.html'

Comment: Sorry there was a slight typo. Try the updated version now.

Comment: Thanks, I have the feeling were getting closer. Now when I try example.com/a/ it redirects to example.com/shop/ instead of example.com/shop/a/

Comment: The loop still occurs, the ! does nothing.. what could go wrong?